# Trying to spawn child process from inside renderer using a button

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I'm working on an electron application where I want to start a child node process (to run a Discord.JS bot).

I have the following code:

`index.html`:

```
<tr>
    <th class="title-bar-cell" style="text-align: left;">
        <i onclick="window.close()" id="close-button" class="far fa-window-close"></i>
        <i onclick="ipcRenderer.send('minimize')" id="minimize-button" class="far fa-window-minimize"></i>
        <p id="title-bar-text">Toggle Control Panel</p>
    </th>
    <th class="title-bar-cell right-indent" style="text-align: right;">
        <i id="new-bot-button" class="fas fa-plus bar-icon"></i>
        <i id="select-bot-button" class="fas fa-box-open bar-icon"></i>
        <i id="start-bot-button" class="fas fa-play bar-icon"></i>
        <i id="stop-bot-button" class="fas fa-stop bar-icon"></i>
        <i id="about-button" class="fas fa-info bar-icon"></i>
    </th>
</tr>
```

`botController.js`:

```
document.getElementById('start-bot-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  ipcRenderer.send('startBot');
})
```

However, JavaScript is throwing an error saying that I can't add the attribute `addEventListener` to null. Why?

Also, do I need to import something for ipcRenderer? Or is it just given.

Answer (score 0):

Where in the HTML are you loading `botController.js`? If you're loading it in the `<head>` tag, remove it and put it at the bottom of your HTML body (inside the  tag). It may be returning null because the DOM has not loaded yet.

Also to use `ipcRenderer`, add the following line to the top of `botController.js`:

`const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');`